# How does quaternions rotation matrix of Unity calculate?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

I don't know how to calculate rotation matrix from quaternion in Unity.

The general rotation matrix is calculated as follows:

http://www.utdallas.edu/~sxb027100/dock/quaternion.html

The below is code of wxmaxima.

```
l: matrix([w, z, -y, x], [-z, w, x, y], [y, -x, w, z], [-x, -y, -z, w]);
r: matrix([w, z, -y, -x], [-z, w, x, -y], [y, -x, w, -z], [x, y, z, w]);
lr:  l . r;
```

Focusing on z-axis(0, 0, 1) in the general rotation matrix, it is the following formula.

```
2xz-2wy
2yz+2wx
w^2-x^2-y^2+z^2=1-2x^2-2y^2
```

In Unity,　it is the following formula.

```
2xz+2wy
2yz-2wx
1-2x^2+2y^2
```

What is the above difference?

Below is the reference code in Unity.

```
public static Vector3 operator *(Quaternion rotation, Vector3 point)
{
  float num1 = rotation.x * 2f;
  float num2 = rotation.y * 2f;
  float num3 = rotation.z * 2f;
  float num4 = rotation.x * num1;
  float num5 = rotation.y * num2;
  float num6 = rotation.z * num3;
  float num7 = rotation.x * num2;
  float num8 = rotation.x * num3;
  float num9 = rotation.y * num3;
  float num10 = rotation.w * num1;
  float num11 = rotation.w * num2;
  float num12 = rotation.w * num3;
  Vector3 vector3;
  vector3.x = (float) ((1.0 - ((double) num5 + (double) num6)) * (double) point.x + ((double) num7 - (double) num12) * (double) point.y + ((double) num8 + (double) num11) * (double) point.z);
  vector3.y = (float) (((double) num7 + (double) num12) * (double) point.x + (1.0 - ((double) num4 + (double) num6)) * (double) point.y + ((double) num9 - (double) num10) * (double) point.z);
  vector3.z = (float) (((double) num8 - (double) num11) * (double) point.x + ((double) num9 + (double) num10) * (double) point.y + (1.0 - ((double) num4 + (double) num5)) * (double) point.z);
  return vector3;
}
```

https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/96fb16e2eb6fff1acf3d4e25fa713defb3d17999/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/Quaternion.cs

Comment: Just a guess, but i suppose general rotation is made for direct (right-hand) axis system, whereas unity is a indirect (left-hand) axis system. That should explain the - sign.

Comment: You are correct!!

Comment: Transposing rotation matrix of right-hand direction, I solved the problem . Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: No problem :)  -

Comment: (I will post this as an answer then)

Answer (score 0):

General rotation is made for direct (right-hand) axis system, whereas unity is a indirect (left-hand) axis system. That should explain the - sign, and the difference you got.